# Android: how can I store images for display in listView?

Tags: android, image

How should I approach the problem I have about storing images for an small android application? Where the user is choosing the image for a record in listView. Database? JSON? is there like a direct link it can be created between the app and the phone gallery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are all the storage options for you on Android framework: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You will most likely use Internal http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal or External file system http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal for storing and accessing your images.